# How to add an item to a listof() function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, geojson, listof

I have a listof() variable with a `Coordinate(latitude,longitude)` data class, for example this is how I initialise it:

```
var coordinate = listof<Coordinate>()
```

I would like to add latitude and longitude for each marker of a polygon by retrieving them from Firebase Database, for example:

```
val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("polygon").child("coordinate")

databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    val numberOfCoor = snapshot.childrenCount.toInt()
                                        var i = 1

                                        for (n in i until numberOfCoor + 1) {
                                            val latitude = snapshot.child("coordinate$i")
                                                .child("latitude").getValue().toString().toDouble()
                                            val longitude = snapshot.child("coordinate$i")
                                                .child("longitude").getValue().toString().toDouble()
                                            coordinate.plus(Coordinate(longitude, latitude))
                             }
               }
override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

  }
})
```

So from the code above, can be seen that I add each latitude and longitude by using `coordinate.plus(Coordinate(longitude, latitude))`

But when I download this GeoJSON file, the coordinate has no latitude and longitude.

So how to add item to a listof() function in Kotlin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listOf` returns an immutable `List<out Coordinate>`

To be able to add items to the list, you can instantiate it with `mutableListOf<Coordinate>`

Answer (score 2):

The `.plus` method does not modify the original list. Alternatively you can use `.add`.

It is good practice to use `mutablelist`. You can add and remove elements.

```
var coordinate = mutableListOf<Coordinate>()
// ...
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    val numberOfCoor = snapshot.childrenCount.toInt()
    var i = 1

    for (n in i until numberOfCoor + 1) {
      val latitude = snapshot.child("coordinate$i")
        .child("latitude").getValue().toString().toDouble()
      val longitude = snapshot.child("coordinate$i")
        .child("longitude").getValue().toString().toDouble()
      coordinate.add(Coordinate(longitude, latitude))
    }
  }
}
```